# Cannot find the models in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Although I have uploaded my dataset as a *.CSV* file to **Weka**, It doesn't show models to select. All the models in the hidden state.

[image: screen shot of weka]

Dataset used as follows

[image: Dataset]

Comment: show your dataset as well

Comment: I just edited and put the dataset also

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the dataset is not applicable for these algorithms.

In Weka, we have **numerical data** and **categorical data**, make sure all the labels are standardized before you do any classification.  Try to perform data cleaning and data preprocessing with your dataset first.

Comment: Can we do the data preprocessing from weka itself?

Comment: It depends, Weka does provides some handy preprocessing methods/algorithms (the page you import dataset)